# How to get a typed object with angularfire 7+ (firebase 9)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I recently started to use the "new" modular approach of angular and angularfire.

I'm trying to retrieve a document from a collection.

Currently I've this:

```
  constructor(private firestore: Firestore, private auth: Auth) {
    const userId = this.auth.currentUser?.uid;
    const docReference = doc(this.firestore, 'queues/' + userId);
    this.myQueue$ = docData(docReference);
  }
```

My goal is to have `myQueue$` typed like this:

```
  public readonly myQueue$: Observable<Queue | null>;
```

But I'm not really sure how?

I tried to do the following:

```
const docReference = doc<Queue>(this.firestore, 'queues/' + userId);
this.myQueue$ = docData<Queue>(docReference);
```

but it doesn't work because `this.firestore` isn't a `CollectionReference<Queue>`(which seems normal since its the whole firestore database).

This `modular` is a bit a pain, most of the doc still refer to the "old" approach: https://github.com/angular/angularfire/tree/master/docs/firestore.

So how can I work with typed objects?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution is just to cast your document reference like this:

```
const docReference = doc(
  this.firestore,
  'queues/' + userId
) as DocumentReference<Queue>;
this.myQueue$ = docData(docReference);
```

Or if `Queue` is not just an interfate, but a class, than you can use a [data converter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.firestoredataconverter):

```
const queueCollectionReference = collection(
  this.firestore,
  'queues/'
).withConverter({
  toFirestore(queue: WithFieldValue<Queue>): DocumentData {
    return {
      /*...*/
    };
  },
  fromFirestore(
    snapshot: QueryDocumentSnapshot,
    options: SnapshotOptions
  ): Queue {
    const data = snapshot.data(options)!;
    return new Queue(/*...*/);
  },
});
const docReference = doc(queueCollectionReference, userId);
this.myQueue$ = docData(docReference);
```

Comment: Yes, it's what I'm currently doing, but it feels kinda wrong. The previous version was allowing me to provide the type to the doc. I guess there should be some similar approach?

Comment: No, unfortunately there is no similar approach.
The `doc` function has three overloads, but only one takes a template parameter T and returns a document reference to T . For this overload you have to provide the collection reference to T .
The `collection` function also has three overloads, but neither accepts a template parameter.
The only remaining option is to use the previously mentioned converter or type casting.
The latter will work completely fine as long as `Queue` is just an interface.
It's sad that there isn't a similar approach to V8.